# What is the correct way to do a search in vscode with regex for NOT the letter 's'

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

This is my find/replace method

```
sometext([^s])
```

It thinks the 's' is either an 's' or a '\s' - ie whitespace.
How to make it so it definately does not think its a whitespace?

To reproduce this problem:
Create a file:

```
sometexts

sometext

sometext
```

Do a search with the above regex, and notice it only finds the last item.
The second item is not found.

Comment: This s is a real s. A \s would be whitespace. This seems weird

Comment: I think you want: `sometext\([^s]+\)`

Comment: The parenthesis, though, have a special meaning in regular expressions. What text are you trying to find? Please edit the question and add text samples that match and do not match, as well as the intended replacements.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen For clarify - I'm not looking for parenthesis in the text. That's for me to replace the 's' with another character. The problem is vscode is for some reason thinking its either 's' or \s. I need to come up with another solution to get around this bug

Comment: @Steve Try using 2 backslashes `\\s` ... this is necessary in some flavors of regex.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks. Tried that but no joy

Comment: You are wrong about the regex meaning. All it matches is a `sometext` char sequence and then ANY char other than `s` (note: in VSCode, excluding line breaks). As in the first two cases there is either `s` or line break after `sometext` there is no match - as expected. If all you want is to make sure the `sometext` match is at a word boundary, use `\b`, `sometext\b`. If you need to make sure there is whitespace or end of line/string, use `sometext(?!\S)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It is not wrong. A line break is a character. Therefore it should work as it does in every other regex compiler from javascript to c++

Comment: VSCode is not like any other compiler. It is a *text editor*. And in text editors, line break matching is tool-specific. Did you use Vim? EmEditor? Atom? Visual Studio? `[^s]` does not match a line break in VSCode regex unless you use `\n` or `\r` somewhere in a regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Atom works. Vscode doesn't. Its not honouring the regex.

Comment: As I mentioned, there is no universal rule in text editors as far as line break handling. Vim is the weirdest anyway.

Comment: I updated the close reason to a more precise one. In general, we never use a negated character class for that, we use a negative lookahead.

Comment: I don't know the exact library used by Code but many engines treat line endings as special cases and even have flags to work in multiline mode. I think you want `sometext([^s]|$)` or `sometext([^s]|\n)`.